# Can't clear an image

Tags: css, image

I have got some code in Html and CSS and some text in html `<p>` as well. I have inserted an image, but lots of space to the right of an image is blank and I'd like to insert my text there. Would be grateful for any help.

HTML

```
<p>
    Istnieje 3 podstawowych działaniach na macierzach - to <b>dodawanie</b>,   <b>odejmowanie</b> i <b>mnożenie</b>. Dzisiaj my zajmiemy się tymi działaniami.<br/>
    &nbsp  <img src = "css\images\matrix.jpg"/> Rozpoczniemy z tego, co to są wymiary macierzy. Wymiary macierzy - to ilość wierszy i kolumny danej macierzy.
    Kolumny często oznaczją literą m, a wierszy - literą n. Otóż, nasza macierz A na obrazku ma m kolumn i n wierszy.<br/>
    &nbsp Najpierw zaczniemy od dodawania 2 macierzy.Dodawać możemy tylko macierzy o jednakowych wymiarach. Jest ono bardzo proste i wykonuje się w taki sposób, że 
    dodajemy poszczególne elemnty dwóch macierzy. Kolejność dodawania macierzy,   oczewiście, nie ma znaczenia. Czyli A + B = B + A.
    Przykład dodawania dwóch macierzy jest zilustrowany na obrazku.<br/>
    <img src="css\images\addingMatrices.jpg" alt="dodawanie dwóch macierzy" />
```

CSS
row is my container, and all text and iamges go in the `<p></p>` tags.

```
.row p{
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:25px;
    margin-right:25px;
    font-size:14px;
    font-family:Georgia, serif;
    word-wrap:break-word;
    text-align:justify;
    text-justify:inter-word;
    color:black;
    text-indent:10px;
}
.row p a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:orange;
}
.row p img{
    clear:left;
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could float the image to get such a result

```
#theimage{
    float:left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/tHWyE/

Comment: I wouldnt use float. I would use display: inline-block; if you use float you will have to use clearfix if you have further content.